# why when using form_for it has to be current_user instead of @user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

Thank you for taking the time to stop by. I have a question which I'm confused about but wish to get a better understanding. On my past projects I was able to do

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <p class="editpage">Profile Picture: <%= f.file_field :avatar %></p>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

but in my current project. When I use @user, it keeps saying required password when I try uploading a picture. I do have :password and :password_confirmation in my private params for my user controller. Currently the only way I figured out to upload pictures without an issue was with

```
<%= form_for current_user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <p class="editpage">Profile Picture: <%= f.file_field :avatar %></p>
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

Can someone help explain why this has occured. I'm glad it's working somehow but I would like to have a better understanding to why it needs to be current_user rather then @user since I'm trying to update a user information. Thank you for all the help and explanation.

**Added information, within my ApplicationController**

```
helper_method :current_user


def current_user
 if session[:user_id]
  @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
 else
  @current_user = nil
 end
end
```

**Error within Terminal**

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-25 02:04:55 +0900
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"e3DrDAhJPV4vgma9tg7wk9g589ZRDNInynWlXDv7oJQ=", "user"=>  {"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8784a00ec0 @tempfile=#  <Tempfile:/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150825-  4587-14jh732>,   @original_filename="10920917_10152994488342090_418253413398867864_n.jpg",   @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;   name=\"user[avatar]\";   filename=\"10920917_10152994488342090_418253413398867864_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:   image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
Command :: file -b --mime  '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c7 20150825-4587-1ka91nc.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]'  '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c7 20150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "200x200>" '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1alffdu'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1alffdu'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "120x" -crop "120x120+0+20" +repage '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1kd13uh'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1kd13uh'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "75x" -crop "75x75+0+12" +repage '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1recdb2'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1recdb2'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh.jpg[0]' -auto-orient '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1vsru58'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1p9nueh20150825-4587-1vsru58'
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/47a027085753557774697c8014ad69c720150825-4587-1ksrnek.jpg'
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 625ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

**UserController*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @user = User.new
  @users = User.all
  # if current_user
  #   @leaders = @current_user.leaders
  # end
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
   session[:user_id] = @user.id
   cookies[:user_id] = @user.id
   flash[:notice] = "Successfully Registerd"
   redirect_to "/"
  else
   flash[:alert] = @user.errors.full_messages
   redirect_to "/"
  end
 end

 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def edit
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  current_user
 end

 def show
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  current_user
  # if @current_user
  #    @followerlink = Follow.where(leader_id: @user.id,
  #                               follower_id: @current_user.id).first
  # end
 end

 def update
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "You have successfully update your information"
    redirect_to "/"
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy
 end


 def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:background, :username_or_email, :first_name,   :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_name, :avatar)
 end
end
```

**UserModel**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :user_name, use: :slugged

  has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id
  after_create :create_default_conversation

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
   :medium => "200x200>",
   :small => "120x120#",
   :thumb => "75x75#",
   :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  has_attached_file :background, :styles => {
   :medium => "200x200>",
   :small => "120x120#",
   :thumb => "75x75#",
   :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :background, :content_type =>   /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates :password, presence: true, on: :create

end
```

Comment: Are you using the devise gem? Also it's a good thing to see what kind of params are sent through the form by looking at the terminal. The password params may be filtered for some reason.

Another useful way is to just put the user variable (<%= @user %>) and see what it contains.

Comment: where is `@user` being assigned? Can you post the controller code for this view so that we can get a better understanding of the problem. It seems like it might be a simple validation issue but I am not sure why it would skip it in the instance of current_user (maybe post the pertinent parts of the User model too)

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev I'm not using devise gem. Putting (<%= @ user %>), I get <User:0x007fabffd58b28> and within the terminal nothing. All files run without any error. When running with (form_for @ user), I included the error on top. I get a rollback transaction it seems.

Comment: @engineersmnky I've added my controller and model underneath the updated error showing in the terminal.

Comment: has_secure_password  , 
 validates :password, presence: true, allow_nil: true

Try adding these two lines to the model and tell me if it works.

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev I've modified from on: :create to allow_nil: true but still get password can't be blank when using form_for @ user. I've included my controller and model under the error section.

Comment: And  :method => :PUT ? Also, look at @user.inspect. It seems like the variable is empty (nothing is passed) because you're getting the form processed by UsersController#create, not by UsersController#update

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev Someone below mentioned using the :method =? :PUT but I get no route matches [PUT] /users. My update route is /users/:id(.:format) users#update. If you mean doing @ user.inspect in console then you're right. I get a nil output.

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev sorry, just noticed that was you who mentioned the :method

Comment: If @user is empty, then you should ask yourself the following questions: Where is this form? To what action is it assigned? Where does the user variable come from? These are questions you should answer.

Comment: Another thing, use $ rake routes   in your terminal and check which route leads to the update action of the user and put it in the form

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev I haven't resolved the route issue yet since I've been thinking of the reason why @ user is nil. Just to verify, in console after User.connection. If I type in User.inspect I get everything within the user table but @ user.inspect gives me a nil. I'm suppose to get variables similar to User.inspect or was I making an idiotic mistake and you meant User.inspect? sorry if I made a mistake.

Comment: When you inspect the variable @user you are supposed to get a set of attributes. Since you didn't, you have to look where you assign the variable and find out why is it nil. More on inspect: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/inspect

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev This is what I get from console. I will check on the link you send to better understand inspect. User.inspect
 => "User(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, email: string, password_digest: string, user_name: string, birthdate: date, zip_code: integer, gender: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, avatar_file_name: string, avatar_content_type: string, avatar_file_size: integer, avatar_updated_at: datetime, background_file_name: string,

Comment: background_content_type: string, background_file_size: integer, background_updated_at: datetime, slug: string)" 
2.2.1 :005 > @ user.inspect
 => "nil"

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev wow thanks for the advice on inspecting. I just did <%= current_user.inspect %> and <%= @ user.inspect %>. For current user it shows all the fields and the input information while using @ user only provides the listing of variables but everything equal nil.

Comment: Glad to help :) I'll add this to my solution. Can you mark it as solved?

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev still don't get completely why @ user won't work but it's a big lead to understanding it. Thanks. I'll be sure to do that. But as you mentioned before, I guess it doesn't really matter which as long as it's sending to the right controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a user with this form.

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
```

And since you just want to add an avatar, then you're aiming for doing an update. You need to specify what kind of request you want to make to the server, so add `:method => :PUT` to your form.

```
<%= form_for @user, :method => :PUT , :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f| %
```

Additionally, you need to have the `has_secure_password` method in anything that has a password.[Read about it here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password). It's good to know what it is and what it does.

```
has_secure_password 
validates :password, presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

I added a `allow_nil: true` so that you can update without the need to specify a password.

One way you can debug what's happening to your variables is to use `inspect`

For example:

```
  @user.inspect
  current_user.inspect
```

If you want to see what kind of attributes your model has, you can use it as well:

```
User.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to create a new user with parameters that appear to be lacking proper validation, so the commit is being rolled back.

Your user model requires password to be present to create a new user:

```
validates :password, presence: true, on: :create
```

However, your failing request (from your posted terminal error) does not have a password being passed in:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"e3DrDAhJPV4vgma9tg7wk9g589ZRDNInynWlXDv7oJQ=", "user"=>  {"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8784a00ec0 @tempfile=#  <Tempfile:/var/folders/83/2r02tq2d3934d30syfmpz9yw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150825-  4587-14jh732>,   @original_filename="10920917_10152994488342090_418253413398867864_n.jpg",   @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;   name=\"user[avatar]\";   filename=\"10920917_10152994488342090_418253413398867864_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type:   image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
```

If you modify your new action in your controller:

def new
    @user = User.new(password: "some password")
  end

And then put the @user in your form_for call, it should work.

**Edit:** I was assuming you were looking for the create action, however, I think Hristo Georgiev offers the right solution.

Comment: The current issue is when I'm trying to update a user picture, I'm getting password can't be empty if I use the form_for @ user. Form_for current_user provides no issue in uploading picture. I also think Hristo has the right idea except I'm still getting a validation problem regarding password being blank.